# How to obtain the transaction hash of each transaction

Tags: transactions, hash

Getblock through RPC method. I can only see the block hash. But I want a hash for each transaction. What should I do?[image]

Comment: I have solved it. Thank you for providing methods

Comment: If you have solved the issue, you should post the solution as an answer to this question so that others who have the same issue can also find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The transaction hash is a blake2b-256 of the SCALE-encoded extrinsic data.

This should be consistent, no matter which middleware API is used, the process is the same to get to that point. For instance, in the polkadot-js API, each extrinsic will have a `.hash` exposed that does exactly this, i.e. it runs a blake2b-256 over the encoded data as received.

Comment: But, you see, in the picture I asked, there is no hash

Comment: The above is not the JS API - so you need to, as explained, get the blake2b-256 of the SCALE-encoded extrinsic data. So call the blake2b in your toolset with the encoded extrinsic, that gives you the hash.

Comment: Thank you, but what I want is the Java version.